# Switch to latest stable version of npm?

Tags: macos, npm, homebrew

I upgraded node via brew without any trouble to v7.4.0, however npm won't update, it just stays on v4.0.5 and when I try to upgrade npm using brew I get "`Error: npm 7.4.0 already installed`", even though if I "`npm -v`" it shows I have 4.0.5 installed.

How can I switch versions? Not sure what I'm getting wrong exactly.

Comment: Have you set your PATH correctly? Try `/usr/local/bin/npm -v`

Comment: The [latest](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/latest) npm version is actually 4.1.1 ATM.